# C/Linux: How to find the perfect number of threads to use, to minimize the time of execution?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Let's say I have a vector of N numbers. I have to do computations on the vector, so I will assign for each thread a portion of the vector to compute on. For example, I have 100 elements, 10 threads, so the first thread will work on the 0..9 elements, the second on, 10..19 elements, and so on. How do I find the perfect number of threads in order to minimize the time of execution. Of course, we will consider N to be a pretty big number, so we can observe differences. What relation is between the number of threads necessary for the time of execution to be minimum, and the number of cores on my machine?

Comment: If you have cpu consuming operations, I would suggest you using 1 thread per cpu core...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact formula or relation as such, but you can judge it depending upon your use case.

**With use of multithreading you can decide which Performance Metric you want to optimise:**

1. Latency
2. Throughput

Your use case has a single task, which needs to be performed in minimum time as possible. Therefore we need to focus on optimising the **latency**.

For improving latency, each task can be divided into let's say `N` subtasks, as you did mention in your question.

Multithreading will not always help you minimising the runtime, for eg: if the input size is low(let's say, 100), then, your multithreaded program may end up taking more time than a single threaded program, as the cost of thread management is involved. This may not be true with a large input.

**So, for any use case, the best way is to rely on some realtime metrics, discussed as follows:**

For an array of size N, you can plot a `Latency` vs `Number Of Threads` plot and check what best suites your use case.

For example, have a look at the following plot:

[image]

From, the above plot, we can conclude that for a array of constant size N, and a processor with 4 cores,

The `Optimal number of threads = 6`.

Generally, we prefer `Number of threads` = `Number of cores of the processor`.

From the above plot, it is evident that this equation is not always true. The processor had 4 cores, but optimal latency was achieved by using 6 threads.

**Now, for each N, you can test the best possible parameters that help you optimise your use case.**

**PS:** You can study the concept of virtual cores and find out the reason why latency starts increasing after we increase the number of threads from 6 to 8.

**PS:** The entire credits for the image goes to [Michael Pogrebinsky](https://www.linkedin.com/in/michaelpog/) and his fantastic course on Udemy - [Java Multithreading, Concurrency & Performance Optimization](https://www.udemy.com/course/java-multithreading-concurrency-performance-optimization/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy answer on this one. You should essentially try out different configurations and then pick the best suited.

Comment: This is actually the best answer. It really depends on a combination of multiple factors, being the hardware and also the software: nature of the problem, algorithm chosen and implementation. You can create as many threads as CPU cores (suggested by other answers) and still your program may run faster with a single thread. The best way is to profile the execution, find the hotspots and try to reduce them by doing things in parallel.

Comment: I agree with @JorgeBellon.  With a bit of care, you could make the number of threads easily selectable and so find an optimal number.

Comment: @Jorge Bellon and Martin James, I request to you to kindly suggest, edit and improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer to this. Intel have the MKL / IPP libraries for this reason; these libraries contain the necessary information for each CPU Intel make to judge what the best breakdown of threads for an operation is. A pretty good guess would be 1 thread per core.

On the topic of how much data a thread should be allocated to process (i.e. how much of the vector it will chew on), a good guideline is the L1 cache size (normally 32kB). If you judge it so that the amount of vector + the size of the corresponding results is less than 32kB, that gives the cache system the best possible chance of delivering data to the thread and taking the results away again.